# How to use erase-remove idiom and increment an iterator in a loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to loop through a `vector` and remove an item each time.  I believe I should use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove).  I believe `erase` on a `vector` invalidates any of its iterators.  If that's the case, how can I use this idiom in a `while` loop?

Here's a broken example:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 3, 6, 7, 5 };

auto itr = vec.begin();
while (itr != vec.end())
{
    // I'll remove a different element each iteration of the loop.
    // Hard-coded "7" here for simplicity:
    auto position = std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 7);

    vec.erase(position);
    ++itr;
}
```

The purpose of the code is to loop through the `vector` and remove an element each time.  I use a `while` loop and an iterator because the size of the vector changes after each iteration.  I'll remove the largest element each iteration, but I'm not showing that code to keep it simpler.  So, the elements will be removed in this order: 7, 6, 5, 3.  Again, that code isn't shown.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? You don't seem to do anything with `itr`.

Comment: The erase-remove idiom and `vector::erase` are different things, though the latter *may* use the former

Comment: ...are you trying to remove half the items in the list randomly?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify my purpose.  I also switched from std::find to std::remove.

Comment: You're going to kill your performance by trying to remove elements from the front of a vector, since all the later elements will be shifted down to occupy lower slots, and that is O(n) each time.  You'd be better off either using a linked list instead of a vector, or starting a second vector of elements you want to keep instead.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is a bad question and is getting downvoted? It seems clearly written. Rather than downvote it, perhaps post an answer showing how I'm going about it wrong.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you mention that it's broken but don't say how or what the current code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::remove()` simply *moves* all elements (not one element!) of a specified value to the end of the container, and then returns the new *logical* past-end iterator. `std::remove()` does not invalidate iterators, as items are not *physically* removed and so the container size does not changed.  Only the values inside the container are moved around.

After you have "removed" everything you want to remove, you would then call `erase()` one time at the end to *physically* remove those items from the container.

Try this:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 3, 6, 7, 5 };

auto itr = vec.begin();
auto end = vec.end();

while (itr != end)
{
    end = std::remove(vec.begin(), end, ...);
    ++itr;
}

vec.erase(end, vec.end());
```

Comment: I ended up doing `while (!vec.empty())` and erasing elements in each iteration.  I haven't thought about the performance of this way though.